# Where is the data from content editor web parts stored?

Tags: web-part, content-database

I'm in the process of developing a few page layouts. I can map certain TextEditor's and RichHTMLEditor's fairly simply - and the concept of the data found in these controls being saved to a field is equally as simple.

But I don't understand where the data from a, potentially, arbitrary amount of wysiwyg editors (for example) being added to a web part zoned is held? Is the answer as simple as 'in the content database' and therefore something developers do not need to concern themselves with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the web parts are added to a web part zone then the answer is really as simple as "'in the content database' and therefore something developers do not need to concern themselves with"!

All the properties of a Content Editor Web Part including the text and things like width/size that you see in the toolpart on the right hand side are :-

- firstly put in to an XML file (choose the Export option on the web part menu and open the .dwp file in a text editor to see).
- then stored in the content database.

Really - for what you're doing its all handled automagically.

Comment: Where can I find some more info about this "content database". Any MSDN articles? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not quite clear to me what you have asked...

Dynamic Web Parts (placed in Web Part Zones) are stored separately from the page, in content database.  Those are XML data about and of a web part. Only XML data are stored in a database.

Static Web Parts (placed the EmbeddedFormField SP Control or Web Zone) are stored as part of a webpage.

Visual Web Part is a Web Part containing child controls stored. The latter are strored in file system of Sharepoint server.

The DLLs are installed on the SP server (bin, GAC).

Update:
The [Configure and deploy Web Parts (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736.aspx) article explains the (pro and contra) of webparts installation into GAC or BIN

Content Editor Web Part (CEWP)  is a Web Part like any other.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking this because you may want to build a web part that has similar functionality.

While I don't know the answer (and I see that no one else who has responded seems to either), if I had to guess, I would say it's probably stored in a hidden web part property. This is how I would implement content specific to that instance of a web part in both classic SharePoint solutions as well as the modern SharePoint Framework (SPFx).

Of course, if you are using a hidden property, that means you have to also implement your own way of allow the user to edit and store those values, and therein lies the real challenge.